# Export selected datable row one by one to text file where every row got its own text file Asp.net C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

Could anyone please tell me how can I export each selected row to a text file where I export all the text files I mean each row has its own text file and put all the text files in one folder

Ps:I don't use a model because I get data from IBM AS400

I just want to use the datable to export  to text file

help, please!

```
`

 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            string mySQL;
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            mySQL = "Select * From MOUVEMSSE.Mouvem11 ";
            string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dsn_AS400"];
            string conn_string = connect + "UID=" + HttpContext.Session["Username"] + ";PWD=" + HttpContext.Session["Password"] + ";";

            db_tools.sg_connStr = conn_string;
            connection = db_tools.Connect();
            table = db_tools.ExecuteSelectCommand(mySQL, CommandType.Text);
            myDataSet.Tables.Add(table);


            return View(myDataSet);
        }

`

this is return the display of the datatable 

enter image description here

this is the View code

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- <th>-</th>-->
                <th>DATE</th>
                <th>ORDBUS</th>
                <th>ORDSER</th>
                <th>SEQUEN</th>
                <th>HEUDEB</th>
                <th>HEUFIN</th>

                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                <tr class="active-row">
                    <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>-->
                    <td>@row["DATMVT"]</td>
                    <td>@row["ORDBUS"]</td>
                    <td>@row["ORDSER"]</td>
                    <td>@row["SEQUEN"]</td>
                    <td>@row["HEUDEB"]</td>
                    <td>@row["HEUFIN"]</td>

                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=Edit>EDIT</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>



#C#


enter image description here
I tried this code in the controller but there is no result
  `  public ActionResult ConvertToTextfile()

      {
          string mySQL;
          DataTable table = new DataTable();
          DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
          mySQL = "Select * From MOUVEMSSE.Mouvem11 ";
          string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dsn_AS400"];
          string conn_string = connect + "UID=" + HttpContext.Session["Username"] + ";PWD=" + HttpContext.Session["Password"] + ";";

          db_tools.sg_connStr = conn_string;
          connection = db_tools.Connect();
          table = db_tools.ExecuteSelectCommand(mySQL, CommandType.Text);
          myDataSet.Tables.Add();


          string folderLocation = @"C:\Users\zarai\source\repos\Sms_Chauffeur\Sms_Chauffeur\Extractedfiles"; // your path to save the files

          for (int i = 0; i<table.Rows.Count; i++)  // iterate each rows to get the value
         {
             string fileName = folderLocation + "\\" + "File-" + i + ".txt";  // file name for saving each row
             string contents = "";
             foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)  // iteate each column to get its corresponding value
                 contents += table.Rows[i][col].ToString() + "    ";  // concatenating the contents

             System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, contents);  // create a text file and copy the contents
         }

          return View("data Extracted sucssessfuly");
      }
`
```

Comment: Please add in your question what have you researched and/or your current errors (if any).

Comment: please see the code that I put now i make an edit in the text problem below

Comment: In your view, there is no mechanism to "select" a row. You have a button on each row that does some "edit" command but there's no `form` tag. So what do you expect to happen when an "edit" button is clicked? How do you indicate a table row was edited? How are you calling the `DownloadFile()` function? If the `DownloadFile()` function is actually called, is there data returned from the DB?

Comment: I change the downloadfile function code and it worked good but i want that i choose from the view the row that i want retrieve it do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code not tested, creates row files on the server in the temp folder

```cs
int count = 0;
var tempFolder = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
foreach(DataTable table in myDataSet.Tables)
{
   foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
      var filePath = Path.Combine(tempFolder,$"{table.TableName}{count++}.row");
      File.WriteAllLines(filePath, string.Join(",", row.ItemArray);
   }
}
```